# Different instance tag on EC2 provisioning with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to provision with Ansible more than one EC2 instance but don't really know how can I correctly assign a different instance tag name.

I tried with:

```
---
....
instance_tags:
      Name: tag-{{ item }}
  register: ec2
with_items:
  - 1
  - 2
```

But then when I want to check if ssh is open:

```
- name: Check ssh port to be open
  wait_for:
    host: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
    port: 22
    delay: 60
    timeout: 240
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

I receive this error:

> 'dict object' has no attribute 'instances'

Is there a possibility to resolve this issue?

I use Ansible version 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

Please learn how output is registered when running module in a loop: [Using register with a loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop).

`ec2` in your example is a list, not a dictionary, so `ec2.instances` does not exist.

Use [`debug` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/debug_module.html) to display actual variable values, pay attention to `[ ]` and `{ }`, and fix your code appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

if you're using the ec2 module from ansible then you will see that ec2.instances does exist but it's an array of dictionaries. With each entry being the instances that you provisioned so you have to access the members from them.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ec2": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "instance_ids": [
            "i-020dfd4ea1872f"
        ],
        "instances": [
            {
                "ami_launch_index": "0",
                "architecture": "x86_64",
                "block_device_mapping": {
                    "/dev/xvda": {
                        "delete_on_termination": true,
                        "status": "attached",
                        "volume_id": "vol-00415be2e41d58564"
                    }
                },
                "dns_name": "",
                "ebs_optimized": false,
                "groups": {
                    "sg-fcef86": "default"
                },
                "hypervisor": "xen",
                "id": "i-020dfd4ea182f",
                "image_id": "ami-e6899e",
                "instance_type": "t2.micro",
                "kernel": null,
                "key_name": "st",
                "launch_time": "2017-10-23T21:28:06.000Z",
                "placement": "us-west-2b",
                "private_dns_name": "ip-10-",
                "private_ip": "10.212",
                "public_dns_name": "",
                "public_ip": null,
                "ramdisk": null,
                "region": "us-west-2",
                "root_device_name": "/dev/xvda",
                "root_device_type": "ebs",
                "state": "running",
                "state_code": 16,
                "tags": {},
                "tenancy": "default",
                "virtualization_type": "hvm"
            }
        ],
        "tagged_instances": []
    }
}
```

Your with_items would work:

```
instance_tags:
  Name: "{{ item }}"
with_items:
  - Machine1
  - Machine2
```

But going back to why your ec2.instances doens't exist it's because of what I responded to up top

make sure to do a:

```
 - debug: var=ec2
```

To view your variable